# Laravel maintenance mode allow IPV6

Tags: laravel, maintenance-mode

I am trying to allow my client ipv6 through maintenance mode in laravel, but it's not working. Ipv4 working fine

Comment: If they're connecting via IPv4 and it's working fine, why are you worried about IPv6? What config did you use? Have you checked that they *can* and *are* visiting via IPv6?

Comment: By looking at the `CheckForMaintenanceMode` class IPv6 seems to be supported

Comment: IPv4 is mine but my client have IPv6  i added it with normal command `php artisan down --allow=IP` mine is working but my client is not

Comment: To be clear, you need to do `php artisan down --allow=your-ip --allow=their-ip`. You might consider making a page that outputs the client's IP and asking them to pass it along; they may *have* IPv6 but be *connecting* via IPv4 to you.

Comment: yes i run that command...not sure their IPv6 change to IPv4....need to check nginx access.log file...they also log the IP

Comment: Yes you were right...his IP is change in nginx logs file.....change to ipv4 somehow..and when i added his IPv4 (getting from log) it work